# How to get this to output with just one Swift print statement

Tags: swift, dictionary

This code produces the specific output but not with only one statement.

```
import Cocoa
var myTeams = ["Titans": ["Bob","Joe","Billy","Dan","Jill"], "Hawks": ["Frank","John","Matthew","Eric","Jack"], "Eagles": ["Swen","Olie","Helga","Errin","Gloggler"], "Falsons": ["Clyde","Dale","Elden","Fred","Hank","Ike","Jake"]]

myTeams.count

for teams in myTeams.keys {
    let matchTeam = teams                //Current team being processed
    let players = myTeams[matchTeam]     //Players in current team
    _ = Array(arrayLiteral: players)     //Create an array of players
   
    print("\(teams) members:  ")
    for i in players! {                  // Use ! to remove optional
        print(i)
    }
    print("  \n ")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce to build one string of the whole dictionary

```
print(myTeams.reduce(into: "") {
   $0.append("\($1.0) members:\n\($1.1.joined(separator:"\n"))\n \n") })
```

Comment: Very slick! Thanks for this solution.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, this was my first question 

Answer (score 0):

```swift
struct Team: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let players: [String]

    var description: String {
        name + " members: \n" + players.flatMap{ $0 + "\n"}
    }
}
var myTeams = [Team(name: "Titans", players: ["Bob","Joe","Billy","Dan","Jill"]),
               Team(name: "Hawks", players: ["Frank","John","Matthew","Eric","Jack"])]

myTeams.forEach { print($0) }
```

I would go for struct and utilize `CustomStringConvertible` to achieve one line goodness. Cheers !

Comment: Cool, I like the solution. Some new things for me to practice with!